# How to stop onmouseleave() from 'bubbling' to other siblings using vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, event-bubbling, onmouseout

I put the below code up on gileslewey.com so you can see the issue easily.

I have remote, animated .gif rollovers set for each span tag in a series of heads--I used `<span>` to vertically center the head next to an image (it's actually the same image, I haven't refactored any of the code yet). The first `onmouseenter` (or `onmouseover`, I tried both) and `onmouseleave` (or `onmouseout`) event works fine, but when I move to the next span head and leave, the `onmouseleave` fires for both. And if I move to the third and move away cursor, `onmouseleave` fires for all three. Can anyone suggest a fix for this, so `onmouseleave` is triggered only when leaving that particular span?

```
    <div id="padding">
      <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><span onmouseenter="over()" onmouseleave="out()">Center for Character-based Leadership link one</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage2" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><span onmouseenter="over2()" onmouseleave="out2()">Center for Character-based Leadership link two</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage3" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><span onmouseenter="over3()" onmouseleave="out3()">Center for Character-based Leadership link three</span>
      </div>
      <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage4" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><span onmouseenter="over4()" onmouseleave="out4()">Center for Character-based Leadership link four</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

JS: (not refactored yet)

```
  function over(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage").src="images/imagemouseover.gif";
  }

  function out(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage").src="images/imagemouseout.gif";
  }

  function over2(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage2").src="images/imagemouseover.gif";
  }

  function out2(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage2").src="images/imagemouseout.gif";
  }

  function over3(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage3").src="images/imagemouseover.gif";
  }

  function out3(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage3").src="images/imagemouseout.gif";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I turned your code to a snippet and it seems to be working correctly.
The correct image is being affected for every span.

```js
function over(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage").src="images/imagemouseover.gif";
}

function out(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage").src="images/imagemouseout.gif";
}

function over2(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage2").src="images/imagemouseover.gif";
}

function out2(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage2").src="images/imagemouseout.gif";
}

function over3(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage3").src="images/imagemouseover.gif";
}

function out3(){
  document.getElementById("centerImage3").src="images/imagemouseout.gif";
}
```

```html
<div id="padding">
  <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><span onmouseenter="over()" onmouseleave="out()">Center for Character-based Leadership link one</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage2" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><span onmouseenter="over2()" onmouseleave="out2()">Center for Character-based Leadership link two</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage3" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><span onmouseenter="over3()" onmouseleave="out3()">Center for Character-based Leadership link three</span>
  </div>
  <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage4" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><span onmouseenter="over4()" onmouseleave="out4()">Center for Character-based Leadership link four</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I also made a css only version that works:

```css
.HasGifs > .In
{
  display: none;
}

.HasGifs > .Out 
{
  display: block;
}

.GifText:hover ~ img.Out
{
  display: none;
}

.GifText:hover ~ img.In
{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="HasGifs">
<span class = "GifText">This is the text you hover over</span>
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/f-tX-7Czy0YAAAAM/lol-antonio-tabet.gif" class = "In">
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/ENGYP4P6VcMAAAAM/uks-unbreakable-kimmy-schmitd.gif" class = "Out">
</div>
<div class="HasGifs">
<span class = "GifText">This is the text you hover over</span>
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/f-tX-7Czy0YAAAAM/lol-antonio-tabet.gif" class = "In">
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/ENGYP4P6VcMAAAAM/uks-unbreakable-kimmy-schmitd.gif" class = "Out">
</div>
<div class="HasGifs">
<span class = "GifText">This is the text you hover over</span>
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/f-tX-7Czy0YAAAAM/lol-antonio-tabet.gif" class = "In">
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/ENGYP4P6VcMAAAAM/uks-unbreakable-kimmy-schmitd.gif" class = "Out">
</div>
<div class="HasGifs">
<span class = "GifText">This is the text you hover over</span>
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/f-tX-7Czy0YAAAAM/lol-antonio-tabet.gif" class = "In">
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/ENGYP4P6VcMAAAAM/uks-unbreakable-kimmy-schmitd.gif" class = "Out">
</div>
<div class="HasGifs">
<span class = "GifText">This is the text you hover over</span>
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/f-tX-7Czy0YAAAAM/lol-antonio-tabet.gif" class = "In">
<img src = "https://c.tenor.com/ENGYP4P6VcMAAAAM/uks-unbreakable-kimmy-schmitd.gif" class = "Out">
</div>
```

Comment: I'm not sure--I put up my code on gileslewey.com so you can see the issue.

Comment: For some reason, the gifs are not looping. But when one mouseout event is fired, they loop once. Use inspect element and you will see that only the correct image is being updated, but for some reason, google chrome is replaying the gifs in other places.

Comment: I added a css only solution

Answer (score 0):

You can do all this just using CSS, for instance:

```
    <div id="padding">
      <div class="box" id="padding2"><img id="centerImage" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/ccbl-white.gif"  display="inline"><img id="centerImage_over" width="59.25" height="58.125" src="images/imagemouseover.gif">
   ...
```

with CSS like:

```
  div:hover #centerImage {
    display:none;
  }
  #centerImage_over {
    display:none;
  }
  div:hover #centerImage_over {
    display:inline;
  }
```

Comment: Does that work? There's an animated gif that would be triggered on hover, but a separate gif that needs to be triggered on leaving.